# Javascript assignment multiplication operators in a loop as a Math function

Tags: javascript, math

I am doing the following calculations in a loop:

**https://jsfiddle.net/0xLvxjar/**

```
var i = 0;
var times = 200;
var friction = 0.9925;
var velocity = 10;
var position = 100;

for (; i < times; i += 1) {
    velocity *= friction;
    position += velocity;
}

console.log(velocity) // 2.218723008169958 
console.log(position) // 1129.722321918849
```

I would like to rewrite that as a Math function and eliminate the loop if possible.

Looking trough the JavaScript Math object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math I am not seeing something to handle this.

Is there a better way of getting to the final result using a Math formula?

Comment: Well, the velocity is pretty easy, because it's just `10*Math.pow(0.9925, 200)`. The sum would be (close to) the area (integral) under the curve (plus 100).

Comment: @Pointy Good one! Thanks, at least I get something out of the loop

Comment: @Pointy have you done a phd in maths or is it something you learn in colleges?

Comment: @AmitJoki ha ha no, I am in no sense a mathematician. I had to convince myself that the "position" sum really would be the integral, and I'm still only partially sure :) Also I had to test the `Math.pow()` thing in the console.

Comment: @Pointy but still you know lot than me, things like *curve*. Hoping they'll teach that in India in higher classes :)

Comment: @AmitJoki I am pretty sure that you will learn that - it's basic Calculus. And I know you'll do really well :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solve it with math:

```
// v_1 = v_0 * f
// p_1 = p_0 + v_1
// 
// p_2 = p_1 + v_1 * f
//     = p_0 + v_1 + v_1 * f
//     = p_0 + v_0 * f + v_0 * f * f
//     = p_0 + v_0 * (f + f^2)
```

At this point you might see that `p_n = p_0 + v_0 * (f + f^2 + f^3 + ... + f^n)`.

From your formulary you might know that this is true:

[image: Formula]

Therefore `p_n = p_0 + v_0 * f * (1 - f^n) / (1 - f)`.

Transferred to JavaScript you get this:

```
var n = 200;
var friction = 0.9925;
var velocity_0 = 10.0;
var position_0 = 100.0;

var velocity_n = velocity_0 * Math.pow(friction, n);
var position_n = position_0 + velocity_0 * friction * (1 - Math.pow(friction, n)) / (1 - friction);


alert(velocity_n);
alert(position_n);
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, sometimes I wonder why do I write code :
)

Comment: Actually you need to apply a minor fix to my calculations to add another `velocity_0` to `position_n` to account for your loop using the changed velocity for the first position change calculation. Then the output of your code and my code should be pretty much the same (but might not be totally equal because of rounding differences).

Comment: There is a slight error in that `f+f^2+...+f^n=f*(1+f+...+f^(n-1))=f*(1-f^n)/(1-f)`.

Answer (score 2):

The variable 'velocity' is the term of a geometric progression (see e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) while 'position' is the sum of terms of a geometric progression, so you could replace the for loop in your code with this:

```
var power = Math.pow(friction, times);
position += velocity * (1 - power) * friction / (1 - friction);
velocity *= power;
```

However, it is unclear to me if removing the for loop really yields something better efficiency-wise or precision-wise. Indeed, it depends on Math.pow implementation details, which in turn should also use some loop.

Comment: It is actually much faster without the loop: http://jsperf.com/math-geometric-progression. Thanks